# Using CEFSharp setting the value of a dropdown list does not get displayed

Tags: c#, getelementbyid, cefsharp

I try do display an intranet html page on a winform using C# and CefSharp. I can open the html page using an instance of ChromiumWebBrowser. I also succeeded filling some text fields, but setting the value for a dropdown list seems not to work. The html fragment below show the dropdownlist sbo_company and the textfield sbo_user that I want to modify.

```html
    <table class="sbo_layer">
     <tr>
      <td>Company</td>
      <td>
       <input value="Refresh" id="refresh_company" type="button" style="width:66px">
   <select id="sbo_company" style="width:63%"><option value="SBODEMOCL" selected="">SBODEMOCL</option><option value="SBODEMOAR">SBODEMOAR</option></select>         
   <input type="text" id="sbo_custom_company" style="display:none">
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>User ID</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="sbo_user"></td>
 </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Setting I value for sbo_user is working but setting sbo_company does not affect the page. I try to do the following in C#:

```
public void InitializeChromium()
{
    CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
    // Initialize cef with the provided settings

    Cef.Initialize(settings);
    // Create a browser component
    chromeBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://x.x.x.x/");
    // Add it to the form and fill it to the form window.
    this.Controls.Add(chromeBrowser);

    chromeBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    //Wait for the MainFrame to finish loading
    chromeBrowser.FrameLoadEnd += (sender, args) =>
    {
        //Wait for the MainFrame to finish loading
        if (args.Frame.IsMain)
        {
            args.Frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('sbo_user').value = 'manager';");
            args.Frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('sbo_company').value = 'SBODEMOAR';");
        }
    };            
}
```

When I open the page with chrome and enter document.getElementById('sbo_company').value = 'SBODEMOAR'; in the console of the developer tools it works. How do I set this with CefSharp?
But it works if I add Thread.Sleep like this:

```
if (args.Frame.IsMain)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    args.Frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('sbo_user').value = 'manager';");
                    args.Frame.ExecuteJavaScriptAsync("document.getElementById('sbo_company').value = 'SBODEMOAR';");
                }
```

Is there some cleaner solution? It seems to be some timing issue.

Comment: Is there any good example for setting value of dropdown lists?

Comment: Open the devtools in CefSharp to troubleshoot

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I prefer to use the LoadingStateChanged event over frame load end. Also check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

Answer (score 0):

It work for me, hope will help you

```
string script = @"var tm = 'value select';
                  var select = document.getElementById('idOfSelect');
                  for (var i = 0; i < select.children.length; i++)
                  {
                      var v = select.children[i].text;
                      var cp = tm.localeCompare(v);
                      if (cp == 0)
                      {
                           select.children[i].selected = true;
                      }
                  }";
browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(script);
```